# Proper way to handle a large amount of relationship resources of a resource in JSON:API format (Content-Type application/vnd.api+json)

Tags: rest, api, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I'm building an api and I'm trying to handle the following problem:

The client sends the Accept header with application/vnd.api+json, so I reply with the resource in the [JSON:API](https://jsonapi.org/) format.

Given are for example the following tables:

- Author
- Article

which have a 1:n-relation - so for example **one author wrote 100 articles**.

**My goal is:**

> GET /author

returns the author (resource object) **with a defined number of** articles (relationship resource objects) - for example the first 3 articles he wrote.

**In this format:**

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "http://example.com/author",
    "next": "http://example.com/author?page[offset]=2",
    "last": "http://example.com/author?page[offset]=10"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "author",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Arthur"
      },
      "relationships": {
        "article": {
          "count": 100,
          "links": {
            "self": "http://example.com/author/1/relationships/article",
            "related": "http://example.com/author/1/article"
          },
          "data": [
            {
              "type": "article",
              "id": "4",
              "attributes": {
                "title": "1 reason why I should use json:api"
              },
              "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/article/4"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "article",
              "id": "7",
              "attributes": {
                "title": "2 reasons why I should use json:api"
              },
              "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/article/7"
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "article",
              "id": "42",
              "attributes": {
                "title": "3 reasons why I should use json:api"
              },
              "links": {
                "self": "http://example.com/article/42"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**My idea:**

Use a query parameter like

```
http://example.com/author?relationship[]=article,orderby=date,asc=true,limit=3
```

**tl;dr:**

What is the proper way to limit/paginate related resources in the JSON:API format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec does not cover pagination and sorting of included related resources. I would recommend to not include the related resources but using a relationship link instead if you need pagination or sorting for them. The downside is having an additional request...

Beside of that I noticed that  your response is not complaint with JSON:API. For [resource linkage](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) a [resource identifier object](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-linkage) (has-one) or a list of resource identifier objects (has-many) must be used.

You are using full resource objects. The difference is the `attributes` and `links` keys. Linked resource objects may be included in the response using a [compound document](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents).

Your idea using a query param to allow the client to control the inclusion of related resources is actually part of the spec. It uses the `include` query parameter therefore. This is described in detail in [Inclusion of Related Resources](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) chapter of the spec. But as said before that does not cover pagination and sorting of the included ressources.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - helped me a lot!

Comment: @Tries Would be nice if you accept it in this case to also help others find solutions to their problems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who found @jelhan response helpful which I did, I found additional information from another json schema
https://github.com/cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api/blob/develop/docs/basics/schemas.md#data

The abstract i found helpful

`We do not recommend using data for any to-many relationships that could have a large number of related resources. For example, if our posts resource has a comments relationship, it would not be sensible to return data for the related comments because a post could have hundreds of comments. This would result in very slow encoding speed. Large to-many relations are best represented using links.`

Also found in the documentation talks about to-many relationships
https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships

`A relationship object that represents a to-many relationship MAY also contain pagination links under the links member, as described below. Any pagination links in a relationship object MUST paginate the relationship data, not the related resources.`